# fancybox2 determines QTWebKit as touch device

Tags: qtwebkit, fancybox-2

Fancybox 2 uses this code

```
isTouch   = document.createTouch !== undefined
```

to determine if the browser is a touch device. This seems to be a problem with QTWebKit because this function exists. Another way also fails because this attribute is null instead of undefined:

```
document.documentElement.ontouchstart
```

So I checked for both

```
isTouch   = document.createTouch !== undefined && document.documentElement.ontouchstart != null
```

Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using

```
window.isTouch = !!('ontouchstart' in window && window.ontouchstart != null);
```

This works in QtWebkit and in Chrome's Webkit.  I have not done further browser testing.